# %PDF- not at start of file - but why?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a few PDF files that I'm trying to read the start of a file via Python code to confirm a file is a PDF format/header. (the Python part isn't 100% important for this question).

I see the following at the start of various files:

Example one (the first 34 bytes as hex - can't see a pattern in any other way):

```
b'u\xabZj\x9ae\x89\xc6\xad\x8a\x89\xff\xc7\xe7h\xc2yhi\xd6\xda\xb1\xee\xb8%PDF-1.2\r%'
```

Example file two (in ASCII):

```
2 J
%PDF-1.7
```

Example files three etc:

```
\r\n%PDF-1.2
```

or:

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n%PDF-1.4
```

These files (with newline/carriage-returns) I can handle (even if I can't see that allowed in the header specs).

I see `\xef\xbb\xbf%PDF-` in `/usr/share/file/magic/pdf` on a linux box. That's defined usage (i.e. Unicode and byte ordering signaling). It's easy to deal with.

I need help with #1 and #2 formats above. Why do I see those bytes at the start of the file? What do they mean? Where's a good reference for these values or are they simply a mistake? (the files in question open cleanly on MacOS).

Thanks in advance - Martin

Answer (score 0):

A valid pdf file has to start with a `%PDF-` line. Anything before that makes your file a non-PDF file that merely (probably) *contains* a PDF file.

A long time ago Adobe decided, though, to also support such files with some arbitrary leading bytes (up to 1KB, I think) directly in their Acrobat and Reader software, and many other pdf processor software products followed their example.

Nonetheless, according to spec such files are not themselves pdf files, neither your four examples nor any files stating with a BOM.

That being said,

> I need help with #1 and #2 formats above. Why do I see those bytes at the start of the file? What do they mean? Where's a good reference for these values or are they simply a mistake?

As far as the contained pdf files are concerned, those extra bytes are trash to ignore.

They don't have a meaning in general. Sometimes they get added because of pdf creator program bugs, sometimes they get added due to transmission errors. And some people attempt to make use of this laxness of Adobe software to add their own Metadata to the PDFs.

Comment: "A long time ago Adobe decided,..." - and that's the sad answer (because my Adobe s/w was opening up all these files with ease!)

Comment: Worth noting that, in such files, the byte offsets in the cross-reference table are usually relative to the %PDF header, not the beginning of the file - at least in my experience.

Comment: Yes. Anything else would be very weird. Also that is promoted by the spec.

Answer (score 0):

My Python code based on the answer received:

```py
def ispdf(s):
    idx = 0
    while s[idx] in [b'\r', b'\n']:
        idx += 1

    # Simple %PDF- starter
    if s[idx:idx+5] == b'%PDF-':
        return True
    # maybe ... \xef\xbb\xbf%PDF- ... which is  U+FEFF - the byte order mark, or BOM
    if s[idx:idx+8] == b'\xef\xbb\xbf%PDF-':
        return True
    # check further down the file - which seems messy and in-fact is!
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753113/pdf-not-at-start-of-file-but-why
    if b'%PDF-' in s[0:1024]:
        return True
    # give up!
    return False
```

It works.